# Chrome shifting div by 1 depending whether window size is an odd or even # of px

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have three divs inside a large div that is 2205p in width.  It is centered and larger than most screens.

Two of the divs are Absolute positioned, one on the left, one on the right.  They are semi-transparent.

The third div is 2205p in width and contains an image also 2205p in width.  This image has boxes drawn to match where the other two divs should be.

Works fine in IE9, Firefox and Safari.

But in Chrome (Windows or Mac) the position gets shifted if the window is an odd number of pixels wide.  (and works fine if the window width is even numbered.

Use chrome and resize the window to see.

http://nicecomputersny.com/chrome-bug.php

Chrome is changing the size of the large divs from 2205px to 2206px, which i assume is creating this effect.

EDIT:  I have recreated the issue with divs that are 2206px in width and Chrome is not changing the div sizes, but the problem remains.

http://nicecomputersny.com/chrome-bug2.php

Comment: I'd say it's a rounding issue due to auto margins. See e.g. [this](https://forrst.com/posts/Fix_Webkit_pixel_shift_with_body_centered_backgr-LQ1).

Comment: I appreciate the response. If this were a webkit issue then it would also happen in Safari which it doesn't.

Comment: I think it relates though.  Maybe I can center the div container with javascript...

Comment: It worked!  Thank you.  (well it doesn't work on the sample page i linked to but it works on the actual site i'm working on.)  I didn't see the full code on the page you linked to at first (something's broken there) so it me a second look to find it.   Thanks again claesv, this has been bugging me for weeks.

Comment: To fix the problem i presented i added "center" to the background (inline) css rule of the large div inside the other large div.  I'm guessing this was also a rounding issue due to auto margins as suggested by claesv.

http://nicecomputersny.com/chrome-bug3.php

My actual problem (which i thought i had recreated) was fixed with the javascript suggested.  I can't officially answer my own question yet because i am new here.

Answer (score 0):

I added "center" to the background (inline) css rule of the large div inside the other large div.  I'm guessing this was also a rounding issue due to auto margins as suggested by claesv.

http://nicecomputersny.com/chrome-bug3.php

My actual problem (which i thought i had recreated) was fixed with the javascript suggested.